# Wearing animal hair or skin during salat?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, sunnah, animals

I heard that if even a single hair of a Carnivore animal(even a cat) or one died in a Haram way be on your clothes; it will make your Salat not acceptable, any confirmation with references please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shia Jaafari feqh:

> ِA single hair of an animal which is forbidden to eat in Islam cause
>   to making your salat unacceptable and ALLAH knows..

Check this [link](http://www.alfaqaha.net/home/art682.html), Marajeaa says that.

Comment: Why the downvote. This is not a personal opinion, this is fatwa.

Comment: so it means keeping a cat as a pet is not acceptable? and why would there be such fatwa?

Comment: No you can keep a pet but you should be aware of its hair not to be on your cloths when salat. You can make a special place and cloths to pray... Why this fatwa, really i can't answer it's a question to marajea. The rule is that you can make your salat and you have hair of an animal which is forbidden to eat in Islam.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pray you must be in a state of *tahara* (cleanliness). So wearing clothes or material that is *najis* would violate this state. This includes, but is not restricted to, skin that has not been tanned.

Animal hair is not considered najis (which includes cats), with the exception of dogs.

There is difference of opinion on dog hair. Most Sunni schools of thought consider the whole of the dog as najis, and so (knowingly) having dog hair on your clothes would require cleaning before you pray. The Hanafi school however only considers wet contact with a dog as najis (i.e. the dog's saliva) and it's hair as not najis.

Comment: This'd be a good basis for answering the question about dog's purity

Comment: This one http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12189/43

Comment: Well i think there's consensus among Sunni scholar that pig leather is also najiss

Answer (score -2):

There's nothing from the Quran that references to such a prohibition.

It would be tough to bring evidence for something that isn't mentioned in the Quran or sayings attributed to the Prophet.

The closest hadith i can think of is in Sunan Abu Dawud and Sunan ibn Majah about black dogs can break your prayer if they pass in front of you.

However, I don't know if the hadith falsely attributed to the Prophet or true.

Comment: please edit it and only mention parts you're sure about! We don't want to spread things we don't know!

Comment: you said::"I don't know if the hadith falsely attributed to the Prophet or true"