# Why muslims are not allow to touch dogs?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, practical-islam, history, dogs

My neighbour has a dog and it’s very playful. I really want to touch & play with him. But my mother told me Muslims do not touch dogs. I asked her why & she said because it’s in the Quran. She didn’t say exactly why are we not allowed to touch it. Is it a sin to touch it?

Comment: This is related [Are dogs impure?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/are-dogs-impure)

Answer (score 2):

**It is not a sin to touch a dog.**

The saliva of a dog is impure. So if dog licks your utensils, then the utensils must be washed 7 times and 1 time with soil.Similarly if a dog licks your clothes, then you need to wash it the same way - 7 times and 1 time with soil.

> It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "The purification of the vessel of one of you, **if a dog licks it,** is to wash it seven times, the first time with soil." Nararted by Muslim, 279.

Dogs can't be kept as a pet. Dogs can be kept as a guard, hunter etc.

> It was narrated that Ibn Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: "I heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: 'Whoever keeps a dog, except a dog that is trained for hunting or a dog for herding livestock, his reward will decrease each day by two qeeraats.'" (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5059; Muslim, 2941).

So you can see the hassle of washing if a dog licks something. Maybe because of this Muslims stay away from dog.

Again, it is not a sin to touch a dog, you just need to follow the hadith if a dog licks your clothes or utensils.