# If A dog licks a surface and this surface is cleaned with a sponge and this same sponge is used to clean somewhere else is that other place najis

Tags: najis, dogs

If someone washed a dog in a bath tub and this bath tub was cleaned using bleach and a sponge then this same sponge was used to clean another shower, is this second shower classed as najis?

Comment: and if someone gets in this second shower is their feet najis aswell?

Comment: No their feet is not najis

Comment: Is a dog najis at all? Why? See also [Are dogs impure?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/are-dogs-impure)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer **No**

Long answer

It is not najis because the sponge is clean(not najis). Just because sponge was used to clean the "bathtub"(where the dog was washed) it doesn't mean that the sponge is unclean(najis).
And you used bleach, so far I know that bleach is used to **clean** the **unclean** surface. And the sponge was in contact with the bleach. So the sponge is also clean(not najis).